# Call class in AJAX response text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have div in which I am getting ajax response

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

And in response I am getting three buttons with id and values

```
<button type="button" class="Model" onclick="ModelAppAll(<?php echo $i; ?>)">Approve All</button>
<button type="button" class="Model" onclick="ModelRejAll(<?php echo $i; ?>)">Reject All</button>
```

Now I want to call a function and get the `$i` values in alert box like

```
function ModelAppReqId1(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Or like this with jquery

```
$(".model").click(function{
    alert(this.value);
});
```

In short I want work with AJAX response like actual DOM element. I am not able to find any class [model] in response text.
Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery to attach a delegated click event handler then you can achieve this by placing the `$i` variable from your PHP code in a `data-*` attribute on the button which you can then retrieve in the event handler. Try this:

```html
<button type="button" class="model" data-i="<?php echo $i; ?>">Approve All</button>
<button type="button" class="model" data-i="<?php echo $i; ?>">Reject All</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.model', function() {
    var i = $(this).data('i');
    // use i here...
})
```

Note that `document` is just used for sake of an example here. Ideally you should change that selector to the nearest parent element to the buttons which is available in the DOM on page load.

Comment: But Now I am not able to send this in ajax url , I am getting values I can alert that value But I am not able to pass it in url of ajax htttp requiest

Comment: You need to pass data like this: `$.ajax({ url: '/your-url', data: { key: value });`. If that doesn't help it's probably best to start a new question

Answer (score 0):

Just to also provide an answer without jQuery:

When calling a js-function out of an html-element like that:

```
<button type="button" class="Model" onclick="ModelAppAll(<?php echo $i; ?>)">Approve All</button>
```

you will have `i` passed as an argument to that called function:

```
function ModelAppAll(i){
    alert(i);
}
```